# Fetch proper records form SQL Server of materials and stock

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a material table where material's reorder level is mentioned and other table is stock table where stock is been updated. I want to write a query which fetches me all the item from the DB which exist in stock table and which having the stock below the reorder level. Following is my query. I am not getting any results. Please point out what I am doing wrong.

```
select * 
from 
    MaterialMaster m
join 
    Stock s on m.MaterialId = s.Stock_Material_Id
where 
    s.Stock_available_stock <= m.Reorder_Level
```

Comment: If you provide sample data in your tables and expected result of the query it would be possible to point out what is wrong